# JpaSpecificationExecutor#findAll() doesn't anymore apply filter after updating Spring Boot 2.7.4 to 3.0.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller that passes a filter with parameters for a search, I call my repository that extends the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface but when calling the findAll method passing the filter parameters it returns all records without filtering. Below are the codes for my controller, repository, specs class, and model class.

**Controller**

```java
   @GetMapping("/{codigoPedido}")
    public PedidoModel buscar(@PathVariable String codigoPedido) {
        Pedido pedido = emissaoPedido.buscarOuFalhar(codigoPedido);

        return pedidoModelAssembler.toModel(pedido);
    }
```

**Repository**

```java
@Repository
public interface PedidoRepository extends CustomJpaRepository<Pedido, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Pedido> {

    Optional<Pedido> findByCodigo(String codigo);

    @Query("from Pedido p join fetch p.cliente join fetch p.restaurante r join fetch r.cozinha")
    List<Pedido> findAll(Specification<Pedido> spec);

}
```

**Spec**

```java
public class PedidoSpecs {

    public Specification<Pedido> usandoFiltro(PedidoFilter filtro) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            root.fetch("restaurante").fetch("cozinha");
            root.fetch("cliente");

            var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            if (filtro.getClienteId() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente"), filtro.getClienteId()));
            }

            if (filtro.getRestauranteId() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("restaurante"), filtro.getRestauranteId()));
            }

            if (filtro.getDataCriacaoInicio() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dataCriacao"),
                        filtro.getDataCriacaoInicio()));
            }

            if (filtro.getDataCriacaoFim() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dataCriacao"),
                        filtro.getDataCriacaoFim()));
            }

            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }

}
```

**Filter**

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class PedidoFilter {

    private Long clienteId;
    private Long restauranteId;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private OffsetDateTime dataCriacaoInicio;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private OffsetDateTime dataCriacaoFim;

}
```

**Request**

`GET`- `/pedidos?clienteId=1&restauranteId=1`

**Answer**

all records without filter.

with this same implementation, it worked on Spring Boot 2.7.4 and Javax.

where can i make it work?

**Cody repository:**

[https://github.com/raderleao/fastfood-api.git](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Have you tried to remove `@Query` annotation? looks like you have defined two different concepts to retrieve data and now another one wins.

Comment: yes, and without success

Answer (score 0):

The problem there was that I could make a comparison in this way with javax, but with the Jakarta update I had to change it as follows:

```
`enter code here`public static Specification<Pedido> usandoFiltro(PedidoFilter filtro) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        if (Pedido.class.equals(query.getResultType())) {
            root.fetch("restaurante").fetch("cozinha");
            root.fetch("cliente");
        }

        var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (filtro.getClienteId() != null) {
            predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente").get("id"), filtro.getClienteId()));
        }
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

Previously with javax:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente"), filtro.getClienteId()));
```

Adjusted with Jakarta:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente").get("id"), filtro.getClienteId()));
```

This way it worked fine.